# Android App Bundle build error: reserved file

Tags: android, android-bundle

The new app publishing format, the Android App Bundle, is an improved way to package your app. The Android App Bundle lets you more easily deliver a great experience in a smaller app size, allowing for the huge variety of Android devices available today. You don’t need to refactor your code to start benefiting from a smaller app.

I'm getting this error trying to build my app Android Bundle:

> File 'root/AndroidManifest.xml' uses reserved file or directory name
>   'AndroidManifest.xml'.

**APK generation works fine**.

This is my project file structure:

[image]

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml, located under `{ProjectName}/app/src/main`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                package="com.XXXX.XXXX"
                android:installLocation="auto">

                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

                <!-- These permissions are strongly recommended and will result in higher performance -->
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

                <application
                    android:name="com.app.webview.Application"
                    android:allowBackup="true"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:supportsRtl="true"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
                    <activity
                        android:name="com.app.webview.MainActivity"
                        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                        android:label="@string/app_name"
                        android:launchMode="singleTask">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>

                        <!-- Universal APP Link -->
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                            <data android:scheme="http" />
                            <data android:scheme="https" />
                            <data android:host="@string/app_host" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>

                    <!-- Push -->
                    <!-- Services that handles incoming message -->
                    <service
                        android:name="com.app.webview.Providers.FCM.FcmListenerService">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </service>

                    <!-- Called if InstanceID token is updated -->
                    <!-- This may occur if the security of the previous token had been compromised -->
                    <service
                        android:name="com.app.webview.Providers.FCM.FcmInstanceIDListenerService"
                        android:exported="true">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </service>

                    <!-- Facebook Config -->
                    <meta-data
                        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                        android:value="@string/id_facebook" />

                    <activity
                        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                        android:label="@string/app_name"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                        tools:replace="android:theme" />

                    <provider
                        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
                        android:authorities="@string/facebook_provider"
                        android:exported="true"
                        tools:replace="android:authorities" />

                    <!-- Fabric -->
                    <meta-data
                        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
                        android:value="XXXX" />
                </application>  
            </manifest>
```

Comment: If that's your actual manifest, why is it under a sub-directory?

Comment: It's located under modulefolder/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: How are you adding this module? Are you just copying the folder into your current source?

Comment: It's the main and unique module of my application

Comment: Would yo mind editing a screnshot of the project tree-view in the sidebar of Android Studio (click the dropdown menu that says Android and choose Project)?

Comment: Sure! I've added and screenshot

Comment: What's in your manifest? Maybe there's a syntax error tripping it up.

Comment: The manifest should be OK as APK building works fine

Comment: Same problem after updating to android studio 3.2 today

Comment: Same problem since 3.2 went stable, no problem with the 3.2 RCs. Changing Gradle plugin to 3.3.0-alpha11 also doesn't fix that.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Am also facing this, i can build apk, but not app bundle. Are you using any aar packages?

Comment: No, I'm waiting for a fix from Google side and using APK

Comment: Same problem here. APK is building OK but not Bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since October 31, Facebook released version 5.1 of the Audience Network SDK. Using

> implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'

fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 10):

A much simpler fix until Facebook fixes the SDK would be to add this to the packagingOptions in the android { } block of your app's build.gradle:

```
android {
   packagingOptions {
      exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml' //This fixes a bug in FAN 5.0.1
   }
}
```

I can only confirm this works when building an App Bundle, I do not know about a regular APK.

Comment: Brilliant, I had tons of dependencies, and I had no idea what was blocking me building the App Bundle because of this AndroidManifest.xml error. I spent hours investigating, downgrading dependencies, etc. Finally I added this, and now I can build the App Bundle (this is a quick fix only, but still works). Thanks!!

Comment: Facebook has since updated the SDK to resolve this bug, you should update to 5.1.0 or later.

Comment: You are an angel, this code worked like a charm. Thank you!!

Comment: Would this not exclude AndroidManifest.xml from your final bundle and thus make the apks unusable on a device?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, my error was caused by

> com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk

I only downgrade audience-network-sdk from 5.0.0 to 4.99.3 and everything starting to work fine. I hope this help you.

Updated:
As Sebastian said, now you can update audience-network-sdk from 5.0.0 to 5.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the file tree right, you have your `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the `res` folder, which migth be the reason why you're seeing the error. Try to put the file in `{ProjectName}/app/src/main` and rebuild the project.

Comment: It isn't there, in the file tree looks like it's inside but is under `{ProjectName}/app/src/main`

Comment: IntelliJ's tree view is weird. The expand arrows are actually aligned with the parent folder.

Comment: If that's the case, can you share what's in your manifest file? There might be an error there.

Comment: The mainfest file looks good. No wrong/ly placed tags or anything like that. Have you tried resyncing the project with File System? Shortcut for that in Android Studio is Ctrl + Alt + Y

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same bug. Had to change a few things before getting a working build. For me it was:

1. downgrade facebook audience-network-sdk from 5.0.0 to 4.28.2
2. downgrade okio from 2.1.0 to 2.0.0
3. update proguard config for okio, okhttp & retrofit
4. not using R8

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer but I was facing the same issue with slightly different scenario. I was not using the above mentioned facebook library but it was some other library, which I could not figure out because of less info by the build.

I had one sub module (say `module1`) which was including another library, which further had many dependencies. So I put,

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

In the `build.gradle` of `module1` and then the issue was resolved.

Just writing this answer to convey putting in `app`'s `build.gradle` might not solve issue for all the cases.

Thanks a lot @Jason for showing the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To those who what to know why facebook library has such issue:

You can download the aar file from [maven respository](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/5.0.0/), then drag it into Android Studio and expand the `classes.jar`. You would see there is a manifest file inside the `classes.jar`.