# File 'root/AndroidManifest.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'AndroidManifest.xml'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

My android studio version is 3.4.0. Gradle version is 3.4.0. I try to clean project, re-install Android Studio, modified Project Setting Build option. So far no luck. Actually, I have no idea what is my actual error. Just getting this error message in build log.

**Update**

Here is my error log, after applying all of your suggestions
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Esc.png

While building my android app, I am getting this error.

> File 'root/AndroidManifest.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'AndroidManifest.xml'.

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 28
       buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "------------"
           minSdkVersion 21
           targetSdkVersion 28
           versionCode 15
           versionName "2.4.1"
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           multiDexEnabled true
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
               multiDexEnabled = true
               manifestPlaceholders = [googleMapsKey: 'AIza------2k']
           }
           debug {
               minifyEnabled false
               multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
       testOptions {
           unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
       }

       compileOptions {
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       }

       lintOptions {
           checkReleaseBuilds false
           abortOnError false
       }

       packagingOptions {
           exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
       }
   }

   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
       implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
       implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
       implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
       androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'

       implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
       implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
       implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
       implementation 'com.github.tommykw:TagView:0.0.1'
       implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.1'
       annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
       implementation 'com.github.ornolfr:rating-view:0.1.2@aar'
       implementation 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.4.4'
       //calendar
       implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.3'

       implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.1'

       implementation project(':YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi')

       //multiple image selection
       implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

       //make initials icon (SR)
       implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
       implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'

       implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
       implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.3.0'

   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App Bundle build error: reserved file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500757/android-app-bundle-build-error-reserved-file)

Comment: I already tried those things. but still getting error, in few case I get error like: `File 'root/res/values/values.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.`

Comment: HI, @Sohanoor, Did you solve this issue.?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be because of the facebook library.
Try updating it.
I think the latest one is:

> implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I update this, and also added `implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.0.0'` but still getting the error

Comment: in build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

This error will happen if `AndroidManifest.xml` file is at wrong path . Check the path of you manifest file , it should be inside main folder.

If this is caused by library you can fix it by adding this inside android block of `build.gradle`

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But already tried this. So far no luck

Comment: can you update your `build.gradle` file so I can see if you added the lines at proper place .

Comment: Hi @ManoharReddy this is not worked what should I do and I did not use any Facebook library

Answer (score 0):

The version 5.0 of facebook library `audience-network-sdk` has the issue. If you download the aar file from [maven respository](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/5.0.0/), then drag it into Android Studio and expand the `classes.jar`, you would find there is a `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the `classes.jar`. That's the cause.