# File 'root/AndroidManifest.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'AndroidManifest.xml' while building flutter project

Tags: android, flutter

When I build my flutter app for release (`flutter build appbundle`), the build fails with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.                  
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/AndroidManifest.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'AndroidManifest.xml'.
```

The same happens when I try to generate a signed app bundle from Android Studio. However, I am able to generate APK without any apparent problem. What might be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and now it works!

> ...add this to the packagingOptions in the android { } block of your app's build.gradle:

```
android {
   packagingOptions {
      exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml' //This fixes a bug in FAN 5.0.1
   }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53068998/3563059

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear your cache . `flutter clean` . Then use latest version of plugins . Open only android folder in android studio and Sync file system [image]   If still not solved then create a new project with same package name and move all of your code .Best of luck